# How do I access a React Class method from outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have a component defined like this -

```
// actioncomponent.js

import React from 'react';

class ActionComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isAction: false;
    }

    doAction = () => {
        this.setState({isAction: true})
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                Some render stuff..
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ActionComponent
```

From another completely different file I want to set the state for the first component **without rendering it** in the new file so I need not use refs or props.

```
// newfile.js

import ActionComponent from './actioncomponent.js'

ActionComponent.doAction()
```

I'm aware the `doAction` can't be exported and calling it `static` doesn't have access to state either. How do I achieve something like this?

Comment: That method needs to be put inside a provider and be shared between two components

Comment: React doesn't want you to update state from outside. To tackle your situation, I think you need to store this state 'isAction' somewhere else (parent component, redux state, context, etc), not in this component, and pass it to 'ActionComponent' through props.

Comment: @vega do you mean a HOC or using something like redux ?  If its not redux can you show me an example code?

Comment: @Doppio I'm aware of the approach that you are saying. However as i said the component is getting rendered at a different page where without traversing the react tree I can't pass props.

Comment: *"the component is getting rendered at a different page"* what exactly does that mean?

Comment: @FelixKling So i have a component called `Pageloader` which is imported and rendered in another component. This `Pageloader` re-renders to the `componentDidMount` function in the imported component based on some operation.. And this component, ( on which `Pageloader` is rendered ), renders another component and goes 2 component levels down and that *grandchild* child component changes state based on some logic.  Now i want this state change to reflect on the first `Pageloader` component and i'm looking for an easier way instead of passing function props down each level.

Comment: It would be nice to see an example if this is possible through Higher order components. I like the way [NProgress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress) handles similar approach. I can import and do `NProgress.done()` from anywhere and it takes care of updating the style.

Answer (score 0):

In React ecosystem you probably don't need this.

You can pass this method to a child component:

```
class ActionComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isAction: false
    }

    doAction = () => {
        this.setState({isAction: true})
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child doAction={this.doAction} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And then in a Child component you can fire this action

```
// ...
render() {
  <button onClick={() => props.doAction()}>Test</button> 
}
```

If you need to fire action on parent, instead of child you might want to structure your state on upper level, or [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

You can also achieve similar goal without drilling props, but you'll need some state management tool, e.g. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or in some cases [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) would be a great fit.

Comment: Thanks @flppv but this requires me to actually render the child component in the same place I want to call the function. In my code structure i have the component rendered elsewhere and i need to set the state of it from another place. Is there absolutely no way to do it in just react?

Comment: You can do it with just React by using state outside. For example you have component `A` where you need state `active` and component `B` to control `active` of A. You can store `activeA` as a state of their parent `C` and pass `activeA` as a prop to `A` and `toggleActiveA` to `B`. It might be a big prop drilling in big apps, that's why there are a lot of state management tools now. They make it easier to do without drilling.

Comment: Btw you also can try to utilize Context API, I extended my answer.